# Gazebo Static Map Plugin not loading

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to use the Gazebo static map plugin following the tutorial at http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=static_map_plugin&cat=build_world. However, when I launch Gazebo, with the command `gazebo --verbose static_map_plugin.world`, the world appears white, and an error shows in the console.

```
[Err] [Plugin.hh:180] Failed to load plugin libStaticMapPlugin.so: libStaticMapPlugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've looked throughout my computer, but I can't find this file, and as far as I can tell, it should come with Gazebo. What do I need to do to fix this?

This is on Gazebo 9.0.0 with ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23776/gazebo-static-map-plugin-not-loading./) by [BillThePlatypus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16137/billtheplatypus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-09-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-09-16**:
the link appears to be broken. Can you fix it? I never heard of Static Map Plugin and was not able to find any reference on google search.

**Comment by [BillThePlatypus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16137/billtheplatypus/) on 2019-09-16**:
I've fixed the link. I made a mistake copying it over from ROS answers.

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-09-17**:
I found this plugin in folder `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-7/plugins`.

**Comment by [BillThePlatypus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16137/billtheplatypus/) on 2019-09-17**:
I looked in that location, and the `libStaticMapPlugin.so` file isn't there. I have installed Gazebo through the `ros-melodic-desktop-full` package. Did you install Gazebo another way, or with extra packages?

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-09-19**:
I have definitely used one of [those](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=install&tut=install_ubuntu&ver=9.0)  approaches to install Gazebo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After a lot of searching and building from source, I discovered that the static map plugin is for Gazebo 10, not Gazebo 9.

---

Originally posted by [BillThePlatypus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16137/billtheplatypus/) with karma: 1 on 2019-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0